# Parse nested object using GsonConverter with Retrofit2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

I`m trying to convert the next JSON to object:

```
{  
   AccountName:"temnoi",
   Parts:{  
      part-0:{  
         Name:"HOME",
         UptimeSeconds:"2143943",

      },
      part-1:{  
         Name:"WORK",
         UptimeSeconds:"2276958",

      }
   }
}
```

> The problem is that Parts isn't an array so I don't have any idea how
>   to obtain them as List or any other data structure.

For now I have such DTO class

```
public class Info {
    private String AccountName;
    private List<Parts> Parts;
}
```

But obviously program crash as there are no array. I use Retrofit2 with GsonConverter.

Can anyone suggest something to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as I don't have a lot of time, I came with the next solution.

> I replace Retrofit2 by OkHTTP and Gson with built-in JSON parser.

After I get a response with OkHttpClient I manually convert JSON to my object.

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(responseFromServer);
JSONObject parts = root.getJSONObject("Parts");
Iterator<String> jsonPartsIterator = parts.keys();
List<Part> partsList = new ArrayList<>();
while (jsonPartsIterator.hasNext()) {
    try{
        String key = jsonRootIterator.next();
        partsList.add(convertPartJsonToObject(computers.getJSONObject(key)));
    } catch(Exception e){
        // in case if there will be number '0' return empty List
    }
}
```

Here **Part convertPartJsonToObject(JSONObject object)** is method to convert part-0, part-1... to object which I need.